# How to use MapStruct with Grails?

Tags: grails, mapstruct

I have a need in my Grails project to map objects from one type (which is typically a Map) to another type (some POGO). There are some great examples for getting this working with Boot Spring, but not a lot for Grails.

I added the following lines to my `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'
compileOnly 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
...
compileJava {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.annotationProcessor

    // if you need to configure mapstruct component model
    options.compilerArgs << "-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring"
}
```

I have a mapper defined as:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface AuthResponseMapper2
{
    @Mapping(source = "access_token", target = "token")
    @Mapping(source = "token_type", target = "type")
    GetTokenResponse toGetTokenResponse(Map map);
}
```

However, I don't see a generated class for that mapper; when I try to use it, I get a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Have you checked out Lombok? From my understanding, this is precisely what Lombok is for. It take properties and maps them to POJO's. https://medium.com/trabe/mapping-immutable-pojos-with-mapstruct-3f0bf4627fbc

Answer (score 0):

Best is to check if a `AuthResponseMapper2Impl` class is generated by MapStruct. If it is you need to make sure that the package is scanned by Spring Boot and picked up as a component.

In addition to that mapping from `Map` into a POJO is currently not supported you can follow [mapstruct/mapstruct#1072](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/milestone/1075) for this feature request

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'm not seeing an `Impl` file being created anywhere in my project dir structure, so I assume it's just something with my Gradle build process. And thanks for the link to the issue regarding Map mapping, I'll keep an eye on that, it would be very helpful for our situation.